# PF firewall frontend

Tags: freebsd, pf

I'm running FreeBSD 9.2 and the PF firewall. I'm looking for an easier/faster way of adding and modifying my PF rules. Preferable a simple web ui.

Is there any software like this available? I've found pfw but that looks dead.

Answer (score 3):

pfsense is a firewall OS and is based on FreeBSD And PF and would offer you a fully web based GUI.

for more information check out http://www.pfsense.org

Comment: Hm, yeah but I'm already running a complete system. I'm more looking for something to run on my existing FreeBSD 9.2 install if something exists.